# Run wordcount on Hadoop Cluster slower than on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce, word-count

I have the Hadoop (version: 2.5.0) cluster with 3 machines.

Topology:
10.0.0.1      NameNode, DataNode
10.0.0.2      DataNode
10.0.0.3      DataNode

Configured as below:

**Core-site**

```
<configuration>
        <property>
                <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
                <value>hdfs://10.0.0.1/</value>
                <final>true</final>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
        <property>
                <name>dfs.replication</name>
                <value>2</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
                <value>file:///home/tuannd/hdfs/namenode</value>
                <final>true</final>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
                <value>file:///home/tuannd/hdfs/datanode</value>
                <final>true</final>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>dfs.permissions</name>
                <value>false</value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

**mapred-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
        <property>
                <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
                <value>yarn</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>mapredure.jobtracker.address</name>
                <value>10.0.0.1:9001</value>
                <final>true</final>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>mapredure.cluster.local.dir</name>
                <value>/tmp/hadoop/mapredure/system</value>
                <final>true</final>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>mapreduce.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum</name>
                <value>7</value>
                <final>true</final>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>mapreduce.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum</name>
                <value>7</value>
                <final>true</final>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>mapredure.map.tasks</name>
                <value>100</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>mapredure.task.timeout</name>
                <value>0</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
                <value>-Xmx512M</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name>
                <value>-Xmx1024M</value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

**yarn-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
<property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce_shuffle.class</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
<property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
        <value>8192</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

**slaves**

```
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.2
10.0.0.3
```

start-all.sh.
**On Master:**

```
19817 Jps
15240 ResourceManager
12521 SecondaryNameNode
12330 DataNode
12171 NameNode
15381 NodeManager
```

**On Slaves:**

```
24454 NodeManager
22828 DataNode
24584 Jps
```

Code wordcount: the same [this link](http://codesfusion.blogspot.com/2013/10/hadoop-wordcount-with-new-map-reduce-api.html)

With the same input data.

- On Eclipse (master machine): Processing in 9s.
- On Hadoop cluster: Processing in 30s.

I don't know that what wrong on Hadoop cluster configure file?
Timing processing data on Hadoop cluster slower than on eclipse!

Thanks.

Comment: Please specify what your question

Comment: Thanks your comment. I edited. I don't know that what wrong on Hadoop cluster configure file? Timing processing data on Hadoop cluster slower than on eclipse!

Comment: Try with some GigaBytes of input data... Hadoop is bad at scaling down.

Comment: @user3671651 did my answer not solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hadoop is bad at scaling down to small data. Since the process finishes in 9 seconds, I assume you have a small input. Try running your program with some GBs of input data and you will see some great difference.

Consider the cost of initializing the tasks and communication cost (network) between your nodes, that are absent in the local version.

**Tip**: You can also use SumReducer as a Combiner and see a good speed boost when running big data.

**UPDATE**: If you are using exactly the code that you provide as a link, then the problem is that you are using a single reducer (by default). You will see the benefits of parallelization if you use more reduce tasks (`job.setNumReduceTasks(num);`), where `num` can be specified according to the directions provided [here](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowManyMapsAndReduces) (theses are just instructions, not rules).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I have tried with 2GB dataset. On eclipse: **1828s**, Hadoop: **1985s**.
I don't know that is it the normal or is there any wrong in configuration on Hadoop?

Comment: @user3671651 did this answer solve your problem? If yes, please mark it as accepted. Otherwise, please let me know if the problem still exists.